# Como fazer um click disparar outro click?

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber se há como clicar em um elemento clicando em outro lugar, algo como isso:

**jQuery**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#button2").click();
});
```

Tentei isso e não funcionou.
Tomando os IDs do exemplo como reais; existem muitos eventos atrelados ao `#button2` e creio que a forma mais prática de dispará-los quando clicar no `#button1` é dessa maneira, pois não posso mexer internamente nesses eventos e nem atrelá-los ao `#button1`.

Comment: Ja tentou usar a função `trigger`? Ficando `$('#button2').trigger('click');`. Da uma olhada em http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @Wakim prefere postar como resposta? Quando postei seu comment ainda não havia aparecido pra mim.

Comment: @Bacco, não tenho certeza se essa é a solução. Digo isso porque o `$(...).click` é um atalho para o `trigger('click')` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click). Talvez o problema possa ser no `bind` do evento (`click` vs `on`).

Comment: Precisa não, pode deixar a resposta.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#button2").trigger('click');
});
```

<sub>Fonte: http://www.theextremewebdesigns.com/blog/jquery-trigger-click-trigger-method-binded-to-click-event-example/</sub>

Alternativa usando `.on` com delegação:

```
$("#divQueContemOsBotoes").on( "click", "#button1", function() {
    $("#button2").trigger('click');
});
```

**Demonstração:**

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#button2").trigger('click');
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#box").append('<p>Botao 2 clicado</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <button id="button1">Botao 1</button>
  <button id="button2">Botao 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, falha minha, escrevi o `click` do `on` sem aspas. Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado, de qualquer forma. Só para saber, no lugar do `#divQueContemOsBotoes` eu posso colocar outro elemento como o `html` ou `body` (sei que é possível, pois fiz e deu certo, mas o que realmente quero saber é se isso pode dar algum problema no futuro)?

Comment: @Patrick pode sim, mas quanto mais "perto" do objeto desejado, menos propagações de evento serão processadas, pois se você coloca no html, qualquer clique em qualquer lugar vai ter que ser analisado para ver se coincide com o filtro ou não. Tente pegar a div mais próxima que vá conter o botão no seu layout original, para o JS processar menos informações.

Comment: O link do demo está off-line. Poderia fazer a simulação desse comportamento?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas feito, grato pelo aviso.