# Clicar em um elemento que dispara o click em outro

Tags: javascript, click, javascript-eventos

Tenho 5 imagens no meu Slide

```
    <li><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt=""></li>
```

Clicando nelas diretamente nelas, o Jquery da conta de executar a rotação.

Mas a minha intenção é colocar um menu em baixo com o titulo dos dos itens do Slide para que o usuário, caso não entenda que é pra clicar na imagem, clique diretamente nos titulos do menu.

Que solução em JS puro eu poderia usar para resolver esse problema? (Sou iniciante e não sei quase nada de manipulação DOM).

Comment: A tua pergunta contém muitas referências a código que não consta na mesma. Quaisquer respostas vão ser tentativas de ir ao encontro do teu problema e não uma resposta assertiva. deverias editar a pergunta e adicionar a _markup_ completa desse _slider_ bem como adicionar o código JavaScript que faz o mesmo funcionar.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23573/como-fazer-um-click-disparar-outro-click

Answer (score 5):

A solução em JavaScript pode ser obtida da seguinte forma:

```
function fireEvent(element,event) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
       // dispatch for firefox + others
       var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
       evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
       return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else {
       // dispatch for IE
       var evt = document.createEventObject();
       return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt);
   }
}
```

Esta função aceita dois parâmetros, o elemento alvo e o evento a despoletar nesse elemento alvo.

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/r79tkrzx/).

## Exemplo

Em baixo segue um exemplo de uso onde temos um `alert()` no primeiro elemento, estando o segundo elemento a fazer uso da função em cima apresentada para que quando o mesmo receba um clique, o evento de clique do primeiro elemento seja despoletado:

```js
function fireEvent(element,event) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
       // dispatch for firefox + others
       var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
       evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
       return element.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else {
       // dispatch for IE
       var evt = document.createEventObject();
       return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt);
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="meuElemento" onclick="alert('bubu');">
  Se clicares aqui dá um alert()
</div>

<div onclick="fireEvent(document.getElementById('meuElemento'), 'click');">
  Se clicares aqui, vai despoletar o clique no elemento que tem o alert()
</div>
```

## Documentação

Documentação sobre o método [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) e sobre o método [`fireEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28VS.85%29.aspx) do Internet Explorer:

- Método `fireEvent`

  > Dispara o evento especificado no objeto.
- Método `dispatchEvent`

  > Despoleta um evento no elemento alvo especificado, invocando os eventlisteners afetados na ordem apropriada. As regras de processamento de eventos normais (incluindo a captura e fase de bolha opcional) aplicam-se a eventos despoletados manualmente com `dispatchEvent()`.

**Nota:**
Para aprofundar, pode ser lida a documentação sobre [Document Object Model Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) onde se refere a [interface `EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-registration), introduzida no DOM nível 2, onde é explicado o objetivo desta interface bem como o seu funcionamento em maior detalhe.

---

<sup>Código da função originalmente publicado no post [Firing Javascript Events (like onchange)](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly) do website jehiah.cz cujo mesmo foi publicado por @jehiah em 2008-01-23, tendo sido posteriormente otimizado [nesta reposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143771/352449) do SOEN publicada por @Chris MacDonald.</sup>