# Disparar evento click com trigger não funciona como esperado

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugin, trigger

Estou usando o plugin de Wordpress MetaSlider para slides, e nele é possível adicionar links para as imagens.

Criei um botão e preciso simular o `click`, como estivesse clicando na imagem ativa no momento no slider.
Estou usando o `trigger` para fazer a simulação, mas não consigo fazer o `trigger` funcionar.

```
<div class="img-slider">
        <?php
            echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=135]");
        ?>
        <div class="div-button-box-slider">
            <button class="button saiba-mais"> SAIBA MAIS </button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Imagem do código gerado pelo plugin:
[image: imagem]
Script:

```
<script>

jQuery('.saiba-mais').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   console.log( "You clicked!" );
    jQuery(".flex-viewport .slides .flex-active-slide a").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Talvez o seu `click` não esteja dentro de $.ready ou onload, tente usar `$(document).on("click", ".saiba-mais", function() {. ..})` ... Possivel duplicata de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23573/3635

Comment: Está dentro de $.ready Guilherme. O Problema está no trigger, pois a função executa até o console.log.

Comment: votei para fechar como "ampla demais", pois você não apresentou a estrutura HTML, porém eu retirei o voto para fechar. Espero que a minha resposta ajude.

Comment: No teu código não vejo essas classes `flex.viewport` nem `slides`. Eu mudaria o jQuery para `jQuery(".flex-active-slide a").click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema baseado nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working

Resultado:
`<script>
                    jQuery('.saiba-mais').on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var target = jQuery(".flex-active-slide a");
                        console.log("You clicked in " + target.attr('href'));
                        console.log(target[0]);
                        target[0].click();
                    });
                </script>`

Comment: Quer dizer que o seletor estava errado?

Comment: Era a posição da variavel target que estava faltando. Como é retornado um objeto, a URL é a primeira posição.

Comment: A unicas coisa que você mudou foram o seletor para `".flex-active-slide a"` e extraiu o target de um objeto jquery para dom usando `[0]`. Não entendi a "posição da variavel"

Comment: Me expressei errado. É que o retorno é um objeto, e o primeiro elemento é o link, então eu passo a posição [0]. Alterei os seletores para não fica grande, mas eles existem, são gerados pelo plugin MetaSlider.

Comment: Você quer dizer que trocar `target.trigger("click");` por que fez a diferença `target[0].click();`?

Answer (score 0):

É provável que o seletor esteja errado, para fazer o teste use o `console.log` (notei que você já está familiarizada com o recursos avançados do navegador e do javascript então não irei entrar em detalhes), exemplo:

```
jQuery('.saiba-mais').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = jQuery(".flex-viewport .slides .flex-active-slide a");
    console.log("You clicked!", target.length);
    target.trigger("click");
});
```

- No `console.log` deve aparece algo como:

  > You clicked!, 2
- Se aparecer:

  > You clicked!, 0

  Significa que o seletor está incorreto. O `0` indica que não foram encontrados elementos.