# Fazer um click disparar outro click após 1 segundo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como fazer um click em um botão disparar outro click após 1 segundo.

Achei [esta solução aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23573/como-fazer-um-click-disparar-outro-click/#answer-23575). Mas gostaria de acrescentar este atraso de 1 segundo.

### Código:

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
  $("#button2").trigger('click');
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#box").append('<p>Botao 2 clicado</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <button id="button1">Botao 1</button>
  <button id="button2">Botao 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode adicionar um [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```js
$("#button1").click(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button2").trigger('click');
  }, 1000);
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
  $("#box").append('<p>Botao 2 clicado</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <button id="button1">Botao 1</button>
  <button id="button2">Botao 2</button>
</div>
```

O primeiro parâmetro é uma função com os comandos que você quer executar após o tempo determinado.

O segundo parâmetro é o tempo em milissegundos (no caso 1000ms = 1s).